# web servers several instances with different config tmp and ports

Tags: linux, nginx

Using systemd how to create several services of engine X with individual ports, conf and tmp files

as far i as i got i need to create copy /etc/nginx/nginx.conf nginx2.conf and nginx3.conf - there i specify different path to log, change port

then i run

```
sudo systemctl edit nginx
```

then paste original settings to override ?

do i need to edit Enviroment or ExecStart section?

[Unit]
Description=The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
After=network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -s reload
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=process
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

---

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1906/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1219/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1213/cupsd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1510/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2359/sshd: grant@pt
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3028/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      701/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1344/nginx: master
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:865             0.0.0.0:*                           701/rpcbind
udp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*                           1906/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           1906/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           1025/dhclient
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           701/rpcbind
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           697/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43438           0.0.0.0:*                           697/avahi-daemon: r
```

Comment: https://www.mankier.com/8/nginx

Comment: as other people state, you may not need to have different engines just to run a nginx with different configurations for services on different ports.  but if you decide you still need to you may want to use a systemd template.  here's a reference https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-template-unit-files/

Answer (score 0):

> Using systemd how to create several services of engine X with individual ports, conf and tmp files

You can and should do it all in one nginx instance.

```
[Unit]
Description=The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
After=network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx2.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx2.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx2.conf  
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'exec -a nginx2 /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx2.conf'
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx2.conf -s reload
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=process
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I guess you got idea.

https://www.mankier.com/8/nginx

Put it in dir where original `nginx.service` is with the name like    `nginx2.service`. Then `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl start nginx2.service`

Comment: sorry for delayed answer. I need two separate engine X because of task. do i need to put copy of second unit there? /etc/systemd/system

Comment: Put it in dir  where original nginx.service is with name  like    nginx2.service. Then systemctl daemon-reload and systemctl start nginx2.service

Comment: great! thx how to change the result of netstat command

 from /nginx: master to /nginx2: master

Comment: What netstat -4npl outputs when both nginx started

Comment: Check new ExecStart in an answer

Comment: i replaced nginx2.conf with provided ExecStart, then i ran  systemctl daemon-reload, then ran systemctl restart nginx2  but nothing has changed.

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3028/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1344/nginx: master

Comment: You have only one nginx: master in  netstat -4npl output?

Comment: i'm not able to paste all text in comments, i placed the result of netstat -4npl in my question

Comment: actually i have two. original ngnix is running on 80 port, second ngnix is running on 2080 port

Comment: If it is what you want dont try to change process name. It's mostly unsupported feature on Linux. Do not overcomplicate.

Comment: thx. sorry for disturbing,  the last issue i'm trying to set custom 404.html error page for nginx2.  in nginx2.conf i replaced section with error page : error_page 404 /custom_404.html;
        location = /custom_404.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;
}
in /usr/share/nginx/html  i made copy of 404.html with name custom_404 .html but nginx2 still uses 404.html